# Parsing optional argument from \newenvironment to \newmdenv

Tags: environments, mdframed, parsing, environment-variables

I'd like to parse an optional variable from a custom \newenvironment{example} to an mdframed environment \mytextbox nested in the *example* environment.

What I'd like to achieve is something like

Example 1.1 *[Optional example title]*

and the rest of the text in the framed box.

So far, I have the desired mdframed formatting I'd like, (spacing, "Example X.X", etc.) but I cant figure out how to put in the optional title correctly. It's being printed into the mdframed test area instead of the title area.

This is possibly a simple oversight and I'm being stupid with the limited knowledge I have on macros and environments, it's my first time using them, which is why I'm here :)

Below is a MWE and a sample output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=170mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcounter{exampleCounter}[section]
\newmdenv[
        linewidth=1pt,%
        frametitlerule=true,%
        backgroundcolor=black!3,%
        innerleftmargin=10mm,%
        innerrightmargin=10mm,%
        innerbottommargin=10mm,%
        ]
    {mytextbox}
\newenvironment{example}
[1][]
    {\refstepcounter{exampleCounter}
        \begin{mytextbox}[frametitle={Example~\thechapter.\theexampleCounter.~##1}]
    }
    {\end{mytextbox}}

\usepackage{setspace}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}{\textit{Optional example title}}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed `##1` to `#1`.  Also, in the invocation, one needs to use square brackets for optional arguments: `\begin{example}[\textit{Optional example title}]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=170mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcounter{exampleCounter}[section]
\newmdenv[
        linewidth=1pt,%
        frametitlerule=true,%
        backgroundcolor=black!3,%
        innerleftmargin=10mm,%
        innerrightmargin=10mm,%
        innerbottommargin=10mm,%
        ]
    {mytextbox}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
    {\refstepcounter{exampleCounter}
        \begin{mytextbox}[frametitle={Example~\thechapter.\theexampleCounter.~#1}]
    }
    {\end{mytextbox}}

\usepackage{setspace}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}[\textit{Optional example title}]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected... I was dumb. But I discovered a lot while trying to search for alternative solutions. I would highly recommend the exsheets package for question-solution type layouts for tutorials, exercises and exams. I ended up embedding a custom NewQuSolPair from exsheets with a NewDocumentEnvironment offered by the xpatch package. This worked exceptionally well, though the only drawback is I don't have a line under the "Example" heading. But I can live with that. Thanks for the reply though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JeanJordaan I'm glad you found an appropriate approach and learned new things along the way.  Carry on bravely!